# Run jupyter notebook/ juptyerLite with installing (no root permission) on Linux

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I don’t have root access for the Linux machine and I want to run Jupyter notebook/ juptyerLite on it. I can’t use pip to install it. Is there any way to run Jupyter notebook or JupyterLite without installing or running without root permission? I need to write basic scripts as part of my office work.

Comment: This sounds strange but what about running a notebook at eg. Google Colab?

Comment: I need to access the local disk paths on a Linux machine. so Need to run locally.

Comment: What about the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40852267/installing-pip-locally-without-root-privileges)?

Comment: I was able to install Jupyter notebook using by creating a virtual environment. I can see its installed using 'pip list' but when I run it using 'jupyter notebook' it says "Command not found"

Answer (score 1):

Try using [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html). It can install in your user's home directory. Then, you can create a local Python environment and use pip.